# Как поменять цвет элементов меню в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть скрипт:

```
def red():
global actbg, actfg, bg
actbg = "#A2000C"
actfg = "#F80012"
bg = "#A2000C"

def green():
global actbg, actfg, bg
actbg = "#5D7927"
actfg = "#363C28"
bg = "#182400"


themes_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg)
themes_menu.add_command(label="Красная тема", command=red)
themes_menu.add_command(label="Зелёная тема", command=green)

file_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg)
file_menu.add_command(label="Сохранить", command=text_save)
file_menu.add_command(label="Открыть", command=text_open)
file_menu.add_command(label="Создать новое окно", command=new_window)

font_size_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg)
font_size_menu.add_command(label="10px", command=px10)
font_size_menu.add_command(label="15px", command=px15)
font_size_menu.add_command(label="18px", command=px18)
font_size_menu.add_command(label="24px", command=px24)

weight_text_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg)
weight_text_menu.add_command(label='Жирный', command=bold)
weight_text_menu.add_command(label="Наклонистый", command=italic)
weight_text_menu.add_command(label="Подчёркивание", command=underline_text)
weight_text_menu.add_command(label="Зачёркивание", command=overstrike_text)

font_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg)
font_menu.add_cascade(label="Размеры текста", menu=font_size_menu)
font_menu.add_cascade(label="Эффекты текста", menu=weight_text_menu)
font_menu.add_command(label="Сбросить настройки", command=reset_font)

edit_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Очистить", command=clearT)
edit_menu.add_cascade(label="Шрифт", menu=font_menu)

autosave_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg)
autosave_menu.add_command(label="Включить", command=autosave_turn)
autosave_menu.add_command(label="Выключить", command=autosave_off)

main_menu = Menu(activebackground=actbg, activeforeground=actfg, background=bg)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=file_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Редактировать", menu=edit_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Внешний вид", menu=themes_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Автосохранение", menu=autosave_menu)
main_menu.add_command(label="О программе", command=about)
```

Две функции: red() и green() отвечают за изменение темы, но они не работают

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.